# Configure Eclipse CDT project running from Windows/Linux

Tags: eclipse, configuration, eclipse-cdt

In one of the Eclipse CDT project (for embedded target), we need to support both Windows and Linux environment.  With traditional Makefiles, I know how to pull in different configuration depending on the OS type (ie. path to tools, etc)

What's the best practice to handle this in Eclipse?  I know I can manually change all the settings on the GUI, but I would rather just change it once and then save it.  And then the other developers would just pull in this "configuration template".  Or better yet, is there a way to have eclipse dynamically pull in different config depending on which OS it's running on?  So that the project file can be check-in, and when someone update a compiler option, for example, it can be seen by others as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To make a new build configuration, right-click the project and choose `properties`. In the properties window, click `C/C++ Build` in the left pane, and then click `Manage Configurations` (in the top right). Then click `New` to create a new config and give it a name. Then you can choose this new config and change it to your needs. As far as I know, you have to repeat it for each project.

Regarding your 2nd question, I don't know if Eclipse can dynamically load a config depending on the OS; however, I think that checking-in the project file is anyway recommended, e.g if someone adds a new source code file, it changes the project file to include this new file into the project.

Comment: My answer assumes you want to keep changes of the build configuration. If you need to save other settings, please elaborate, which settings exactly you need to change and keep.

Comment: Does this get saved in the .cproject?  So if I share this, others will pick up the changes also, right?

Comment: Yes, generally speaking, build settings are saved in the .cproject file, and Eclipse 'wrapper' build settings (such as weather to auto build after clean etc.) are saved in the .project file